# arrow function vs normal function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and having trouble understanding the difference between arrow function and normal function when including this keyword, here is the example I read from MDN:

```
var obj = { // does not create a new scope
  i: 10,
  b: () => console.log(this.i, this),
  c: function() {
    console.log(this.i, this);
  }
}

obj.b(); // prints undefined, Window {...} (or the global object)
obj.c(); // prints 10, Object {...}
```

In this example arrow function b() can not access **i** attribute in the object because it references the window

```
var obj = {
    count : 10,
    doSomethingLater : function(){ // of course, arrow functions are not suited for methods
        setTimeout( () => { // since the arrow function was created within the "obj", it assumes the object's "this"
            this.count++;
            console.log(this.count);
        }, 300);
    }
}

obj.doSomethingLater(); //log 11 on the console
```

However, in the second example, code within the arrow function can access the **count** attribute. Both functions are defined within the object but only the second function can access the object's attribute, could someone give me some hints why is that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*Both functions are defined within the object*" - no. The `function` expression is defined in the top-level scope, whereas the arrow function is defined **within the outer `function`**.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so the function b() is defined within window scope and c() is top-level scope?

Comment: I was talking about the second example. In the first example, the `b` and `c` functions are both defined in the same scope.

Comment: I was confused why b() can not access property i while c() can access i

Comment: That's because of the different `this` values in your example calls. Did you read the explanation in the duplicates linked by @CertainPerformance?